# In MVC, UrlEncode of Encryption.Encrypt is not working on production and getting 404 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, encryption, visual-studio-2015, web-config

In my MVC appilcation, to Encrypt my userid in querystring, i added following code lines:

```
return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Encryption.Encrypt(ui.UserId.ToString()));
```

and

```
Users user = new Users(Conversion.ParseInt(Encryption.Decrypt(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(ID.ToString()))));
```

First i got this error
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence. which i fixed by adding configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering@allowDoubleEscaping setting in web.confg file.

```
<system.webServer>  
<security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
</security>
</system.webServer>
```

then it start working on local, when i moved this code to production then getting this error:
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Instead of encrypting the UserID why not issue the user a GUID and store that in a cross reference table with the users real id.

Comment: No i have other constraint, i have to solve this issue with url encryption.

Comment: I found that issue is only with those URL which have '+' symbol in URL, i mean when generated encrypted URL have '+' sign then this issue occur otherwise its working fine..

Comment: '+' sign is there because of space. So can you replace that space with underscore('_') or something else.

Comment: if '+' in  encrypted URL and we replace it with '_' but in other end when we are going to decode it then how we distinguishes the  original '_' and '_' for + sign.